# App engine App.yaml. what to include if I want to use a source php file?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I have a search.php file that is supposed to interact with my index.php file for autocomplete. The search.php file content Google Cloud SQL information. In my app.yaml, I have specify the env_variables for cloud SQL, but I am not sure what should I write in app.yaml for the search.php file. 
My app.yaml is like:

```
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes
handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: .*
  script: index.php

env_variables:

  MYSQL_DSN: mysql:unix_socket=/cloudsql/myprojectexample:us-central1:product;dbname=pd
  MYSQL_USER: root
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
```

A part of my index.php: (just show you where the search.php going to be used)

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#456" ).autocomplete({
      source: 'search.php',
      minLength: 3
    });
  });
  </script>
```

So, how should I include search.php in App.yaml to let it work? so far, the app engine won't interact with Cloud SQL.

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a handler for your search.php file, and have your .* handler catch everything else. eg

```
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes
handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: /search.php
  script: search.php
- url: .*
  script: index.php
```

The handlers will be read in order until a match is found. So any time you try to call search.php it will point to your search.php file, and any time any other file is called it will point to index.php

You can also use the app.yaml file to organise your handlers or endpoints.

eg:

```
handlers:
- url: /api/search.php
  script: search.php
- url: /api/authenticate.php
  script: authenticate.php
```

You can also use this to remove the need for specifying the .php or file extension in the request.

```
handlers:
- url: /search/.*
  script: search.php
```

Now anytime you call /search or yourappdomain.appspot.com/search you will hit the search page.
You can add as many handlers as you like, but remember they are searched in the order they are written, and as soon as a match is found the match will be executed. So have you catch-all handlers at the end!